# Why are FSGetCatalogInfo and getResourceValue giving different results?

Tags: macos

I have a piece of file access code which uses FSGetCatalogInfo to get info about a bundle (say .xyz) which itself contains a file with extension .xyz. Because FSGetCatalogInfo has been updated, I am looking to replace it with 'getResourceValue' API from Foundation layer. However, the OSType is coming incorrect from the new API.

I have also looked into the related FSSetCatalogInfo API. Do I need to do something equivalent such that the 'getResourceValue' API will start giving correct results?